# Retrieving All Days Specific in A Month

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm trying to retrieve all of the Mondays and Tuesdays and the last Sunday of every month with Carbon since a specific date in the past. 
Then I would like to loop through the array of days and create an even for that day. I'm trying to figure out how to do that?

```
// Get all dates of Mondays, Tuesdays, last Sundays of every Month since the first Monday of January of 2000.
$eventDates = Carbon::parse('first Monday of January 2000');

$i = 0;
while($eventDates->lt(Carbon::now()->subDay(14))) {

    $event = factory(Event::class)->create([
        'date' => $eventDate,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there's a more performant way of doing this but I'm not that familiar with Carbon. Here, you'll get 3 arrays, each with each Monday, Tuesdays and last Sundays of each month since 2000. You can then iterate over each `DatePeriod`, or merge the intervals to get one big `DatePeriod`, to create your events.

```
<?php
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\CarbonInterval;
$monday = Carbon::parse('First Monday of January 2000');
$tuesday = Carbon::parse('First Tuesday of January 2000');
$sunday = Carbon::parse('Last Sunday of January 2000');
$now = Carbon::now();
$mondays = new DatePeriod(
    $monday,
    CarbonInterval::week(),
    $now
);
$tuesdays = new DatePeriod(
    $tuesday,
    CarbonInterval::week(),
    $now
);
$sundays = new DatePeriod(
    $sunday,
    CarbonInterval::week(4),
    $now
);

$allDays = [];
foreach ($mondays as $day) {
    $allDays[] = $day;
}
foreach ($tuesdays as $day) {
    $allDays[] = $day;
}
foreach ($sundays as $day) {
    $allDays[] = $day;
}
usort($allDays, function ($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
});
foreach ($allDays as $day) {
    echo $day->format("M D Y-m-d")."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I've tried using the collection method merge and for some reason, it isn't merging. I was going to try and merge all into one main array and then sort by the date.

Comment: I've edited the post. It's even uglier than before, but it's sorting them all into one array now.

Comment: @ishegg Checkout my answer. That is probably how one should go about doing this.

Answer (score 2):

### You can use Carbon's `filter()` and `isWeekday()` method to a date period:

```php
$period = CarbonPeriod::between('2020-03-01', '2020-03-31')->filter('isWeekday');
foreach ($period as $date) {
  $days[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
echo implode('<br>', $days);
```

This will print out

```sh
2020-03-02
2020-03-03
2020-03-04
2020-03-05
2020-03-06
2020-03-09
2020-03-10
2020-03-11
2020-03-12
2020-03-13
2020-03-16
2020-03-17
2020-03-18
2020-03-19
2020-03-20
2020-03-23
2020-03-24
2020-03-25
2020-03-26
2020-03-27
2020-03-30
2020-03-31
```

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period